# React native Flatlist renders large data very slow

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I am using flatlist to render my data in react native but flatlist renders large amount of data very slow and after scrolling fast it re-renders the data. Due to which my app takes lots of time to display full data. I also got message like

`VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate`

I have tried all flatlist optimization techniques still flatlist rendering is slow. Any suggestions, how to solve this?

my flatlist component look like

```
<FlatList
     data={questionArray}
     showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
     renderItem={renderItem}
     keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
/>

const renderItem = useCallback(
        ({ item, index }) => {
                              ....
                             },
        []
    );

const keyExtractor = useCallback((item, index) => index.toString(), []);
```

Comment: please can you share your flatlist component ???

Comment: @HamzaHmem i have added my flatlist component.

Answer (score 1):

There are some steps you can try out because it depends totally on the dataset as well as how you have implemented/consuming in your project.

1. Try to make Class-based Component to `React.PureComponent`
2. you can also try setting `removeClippedSubviews` to `true`.

   ```
    <FlatList removeClippedSubviews ..someOtherProps/>
   ```
3. Add `keyExtractor` in your `FlatList` like this:

   ```
    <FlatList keyExtractor={keyExtractor} ... />
   ```
4. Add `onEndReached` Function.

const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);

```
const onEndReached = (page) => {
  if (next && !loader) {
    setPage(page + 1)
  }
}

const loadData = async () => {
  setLoader(true);
  const resp = await getData();
  setLoader(false);
}



<FlatList ...someprops onEndReached={onEndReached} />
```

5. set `initialNumToRender={integer-value}`
6. Found this :[Flatlist Performance](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13649)

Comment: my data set is large and does not support pagination. So none of your above solution is working for me.

Comment: any other solution?

Comment: @venomous31 can you share a small working code on https://snack.expo.io/ ? Will see which solution works best for your use-case.

Answer (score -3):

May be it's possible by "useMemo()"

```
   const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => renderItem, [array]);

        <FlatList
            keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
            data={array}
            renderItem={memoizedValue}
        />
      const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
         <ListItem/>
      )
```

Comment: its not working, i am getting blank screen. data is not rendering in screen.